# Run Powershell Command With Timeout Without using Job?

Tags: powershell, timeout

Now If I'm a Rust developer, I can certainly wrap a future/async process with a timeout:

```rust
// Wrap the future with a `Timeout` set to expire in 10 milliseconds.
if let Err(_) = timeout(Duration::from_minutes(30), async { ...long running block }).await {
    eprintln!("did not receive value within 30 minutes, app killed");
}
```

Or if I'm using C#:

```cs
var task = SomeOperationAsync();
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))) == task) {
    // task completed within timeout
} else { 
    // timeout logic
}
```

How do I achieve something like this in Powershell? (Although some may argue that async block is exactly like a background job)

I wanted to run the Powershell command with a timeout of 30 minutes, but I can't use Start-Job because I need the streaming stdout, since it is a background job and the stdout cannot be redirected in real time (you can receive the output, but it is still not real time).

Comment: You need to use a runspace or a threadjob. Depends on how deep you wanna go.